# Zend deny access on changed url parameters best practice?

Tags: zend-framework, url, authentication, hide

Within the multi-user application I have in my View index.phtml:

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->url( array( "module" => "myModule", "controller"
=>"myController","action" => "edit", "id" => $objThings->thingsid), 
'default', TRUE )?>
```

Clicking this link will lead to the url:

```
http://website/mymodule/mycontroller/edit/id/228
```

where user can edit the record.

Once logged in a user could copy this url and change the parameter to 229 or 130 etc. and get access to information from other users.

What is the best practice to prevent this, set authentication on the level of records and deny access to records of other users? (Of course the records have a userid).
Hiding the parameters in the url would be a step to not tempt a user, suggestions for this are welcome. 
Necessary is also authentication on module/action level.

I have been searching but can not seem to find the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do both. If you want to edit a logged in users profile details, you don't need the id in the URL as you already know who they are.

Then, in your update code, only allow them to update their specific data.

If you have a logged in user, you may well have an object you have for them which will make updating their data easy (depending if you are using ActiveRecord or something else), otherwise ensure you use id in your SQL.